# Enterprise Architect define ENUM data type for PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, enums, enterprise-architect

Is there a way to define ENUM data type in Enterprise Architect for PostgreSQL database?

I am using Enterprise Architect 12.1.1226 Professional Edition.

I have tried to add ENUM in database data types (Project > Settings > Database Datatypes) and then defining a column with enum values entered in the Initial Value field.

The problem is that there is no place to define the Enum Type Name and the generated DLL will not include CREATE TYPE command.

Comment: I guess you need to use stereotyped classes here and adapt the DDL macro. I once did that long ago for something else, so it should still be possible. However, since also a long time I don't use this awkward scripting language any more and stick to the API for jobs like that.

Comment: Enterprise Architect is a mess. `ENUM` type was present in PostgreSQL 8.3 and probably earlier and EA at version 14 still does not support this. Among may other needed things like DDL import from file.